# Trouble understanding how Android screen sizes/density works

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and I'm having some trouble deciding what resolution to tell the designer to send me the images.
I'm supposed to be focused on devices with medium screen size and hdpi density. Specifically for the Android Galaxy S II, which has a 480x800 screen.

Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should skim this entire article:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Then tell your designer to make their designs on a 480x800 palette. So for example if they are going to design a screen for you that has a button that is half the width of the screen, they should create an image that is 240px wide. You should then put that image in your HDPI folder.

I have my designer create 'comps' or designs for an entire screen that are 480x800px, and then deliver all the assets as the exact size they are in the image.